# Code::Blocks how to stop auto tab delete?

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks, auto-indent

I know, I know, I should ask this on the C::B forums, but they're down, so I can't. Right, question: I use Code::Blocks as IDE for C++, but it kind of annoys me how it deletes unneccesary tabs on empty lines every time I save. So, is it possible to turn that of, so those tabs can stay there, and I don't have to add them again every time I save? Thanks in advance.
 - bonjorno7

Answer (score 4):

Setting -> Editor -> Uncheck 'Strip trailing blanks' would do it, but also means you might have extra whitespace at the end of lines.